# MailSlot write sending same thing three times C/C++

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ipc

I have a problem with MailSlots in windows (C/C++).

I am trying to make two simple programs right now, but the communication is not good at the last step.

This is my int main from the server.cpp

```
    int main()
{
HANDLE      ss, sc, sc2r;
   LPCTSTR     errMsg;

   ss = CreateMailslot("\\\\.\\mailslot\\ss", 0, MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, NULL);
   if (ss == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   {
       printf("Invalid ss value");
       return -1;
   }

   for (;;)
   {
       DWORD   msgSize;
       DWORD nr;
       BOOL    err;

       /* Get the size of the next record */
       err = GetMailslotInfo(ss, 0, &msgSize, 0, 0);
           char x[100];
           char nrr[10];

       if (msgSize != (DWORD)MAILSLOT_NO_MESSAGE)
       {
               DWORD   numRead;
               /* Read the record */
               err = ReadFile(ss, x, msgSize, &numRead, 0);
               int wrds=count(x)+1;
               sc = CreateFile("\\\\*\\mailslot\\sc", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
               itoa(wrds,nrr,10);

               err = WriteFile(sc, nrr, sizeof(nrr), &nr, 0);
               //cout<<err<<endl;

               //cout<<x;

               //cout<<err;
               strrev(x);
               err=WriteFile(sc, x, sizeof(x), &nr, 0);
           }   
       }
  return(0);
}
```

Here is the client source:

```
int main()
{
   HANDLE      ss, sc, sc2;
   LPCTSTR     errMsg;
   BOOL        err;
   DWORD       numWritten;

   sc = CreateMailslot("\\\\.\\mailslot\\sc", 0, MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, NULL);
   ss = CreateFile("\\\\*\\mailslot\\ss", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

   if (ss == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
   {
       printf("CreateFile failed. ");  
       // Close any mailslot we opened
       if (ss != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) CloseHandle(ss);
       return -1;
   }

   char x[100];
   char z[100];

   printf("Write the damn sentence:");
   cin.getline(x,100);
   err = WriteFile(ss, x, sizeof(x), &numWritten, 0);
   if (!err) printf("WriteFile failed. ");
   DWORD rd;

   ReadFile(sc,x,sizeof(x),&rd,NULL);
   cout<<x<<endl;
   ReadFile(sc,z,sizeof(z),&rd,NULL);
   cout<<z;

   return 0;
}
```

It seems like the server is sending the same thing three times. I tested the client in debugger and he gets it right, but can't figure it out why the server is sending three times the same thing.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: If "the client gets it right", then how do you tell the server is sending three times the same thing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing [`sizeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91.aspx) with [`strlen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Calling `sizeof(nrr)` will always return 10. The server program will do a single write of 10 bytes, even if the buffer only contains 2 valid bytes.

Replace `sizeof` with `1+strlen` to fix the problem.

For example, in server.cpp if `wrds` is 1, then `nrr` will be `{ 0x31, 0x00 }` in memory. What looks like a repeated write is really a single write of uninitialzed memory. `strlen` will give you the count of valid characters, +1 for the terminating null.

It might be a good idea to initialize nrr, with `*nrr = 0` first. You can test that `itoa` succeeeded with `if(*nrr)` and handle the failure as you see fit.

Oh, and one more thing : you are leaking handles. It might not matter much in the client, but server leaks a handle to a mailslot at every iteration. You should reuse the mailslot handle or close it at every iteration.

Comment: I tried, but still the same, do I have to replace sizeof with 1+strlen in all the read/writes ?

Comment: Just in the call to WriteFile. You don't know the length yet when you call ReadFile

Comment: While this is a great *comment*, it's not an answer. The real cause of the problem is that several transports are used by Windows to send a message (see answer by Jerry Coffin).

Comment: [Windows mailslots are indeed unreliable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365576(v=vs.85).aspx). But do you have a link about the several transport issue ? I don't know what you and Jerry are referring to. I am/was under the impression that a single transport was selected for a given connexion.

Answer (score 3):

Mailslots are an undependable transport -- messages are free to be dropped. To try to ensure that the message gets through, the sender automatically sends the message once using each distinct protocol available (that connects that sender to the intended receiver).

Your networking stack is apparently set up so there are three protocols connecting your sender to your receiver. Since they're (probably) communicating locally, over relatively dependable hardware with no routers that handle congestion by dropping packets, or anything like that, you'll probably get three copies of *every* packet.

Bottom line: if you want to use mailslots, you pretty much have to do assign a serial number to each packet, so you'll be able to track when you've already received something, so you'll be able to recognize and ignore duplicates on the receiving side.

Alternatively, just don't use mailslots. If (for whatever reason) you want something specific to Windows, a named pipe is generally easier. Unless you're actually bothered by your code being portable and interoperable, sockets are probably simpler still.

Comment: I don't know about mailslot's being unreliable under Windows. The network can fail, but that can break sockets too. Mailslots have one advantage over named pipes and sockets : the message receive will always be whole, no need to prefix messages by the number of bytes, or other homegrown framing mechanism.

Comment: @ixe013: I'm not sure if it's still present on MSDN, but most of what I said is (mildly) paraphrased from the Win32 documentation (and, I suppose I should add: I've verified that installing more protocols results in receiving more copies of each message). On a network, anything that's not confirmed/acknowledged is normally considered "undependable" (e.g., UDP is pretty much the same way).

Comment: You are right @Jerry, mailslots are using datagrams. I didn't know that. Here are [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365576(v=vs.85).aspx) [links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234556(prot.20).aspx) for future reference.